# How to convert a fold left operator ":/" into the foldLeft function in scala?

Tags: scala, foldleft

The following code sums the values of the two maps into a single map.

```
val merged = (map1 /: map2) { case (map, (k,v)) =>
    map + ( k -> (v + map.getOrElse(k, 0)) )
}
```

However I am unsuccessful in converting it using  the `foldLeft()()` function.
Here's what I tried , but not able to meaningfully progress.

```
val merged2 =  map2 foldLeft (map1) ((acc:Map[Int,Int], (k:Int,v:Int)) =>   acc + ( k -> (v + acc.getOrElse(k, 0)) ))
```

Whats the correct way to rewrite using the foldLeft function?

Comment: I would suggest you to use scalaz for addition of two maps

Comment: hi @RamanMishra, Thx for the tip! I have just started with scala

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it:

```
val merged2 = map2.foldLeft(map1) { case (acc, (k,v)) =>  acc + (k -> (v + acc.getOrElse(k, 0))) }
```

Comment: Can you break down your answer as to what my version was missing?

Why did you use "case" ?

Also in general how should you approach a foldLeft use case where using pattern match , i.e. the case syntax becomes necessary ?

Comment: How this is different from OP’s version? Other then {} brace

Comment: @RamanMishra op's version has a compilation error, sachav added a case too along with {}, but I am not sure why my version is wrong even tho  I have provided the right function as per the foldLeft specs

Comment: @DevA The problem is that `(a: Int, b: Int) => ???` is a function that takes two `Int` arguments, not a function that takes a tuple `(Int, Int)`. Using `{}` and `case` turns the argument into a partial function with a single argument, and the `case` statement then de-structures the tuple using pattern matching.